# A wheel with $n$ is not homeomorphic to a wheel with $m$ spokes

Tags: general-topology

Define

$W_{n}=\mathbb{S}^{1}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}\left\{ te^{\frac{2\pi k}{n}i}\mid t\in[0,1]\right\}$

$W_{n}$ is called "a wheel with $n$ spokes".

Prove that $W_{n} \ncong  W_{m}$ for $n\ne m$.

We can start by proving that $W_{0}\ncong W_{1}$..

I guess it's related to topology properties, maybe connectivity or connected components..

Comment: I don’t know how much effort it will be to do the formal work, but if you remove the center from any (small enough) neighbourhood of the center of $W_n$, you get $n$ connected components in that neighbourhood (the spikes, of course). If $n > m$, this won’t be possible for $W_m$.

Comment: You can remove $n$ points from $W_n$ and it will still be connected (what points?). Generally for any $W_n$ (with $n>0$) the best you could do is $n$ (Can be checked by considering all possible cases).

Comment: The two comments above by k.stm and Saal Hardali are very good. The comment by k.stm can be formalized without much work, but the really nice general way to think about it is in terms of the [ends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)) of the space when you remove a point. These wheels are characterized by how many points have the property that their removal gives at least 3 ends, for example (or by the maximum number of ends upon removal of a point, though this doesn't quite classify the cases $n < 4$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Start by computing the [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of $W_n$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to use algebraic topology.  Contract along a subcomplex to show that $W_n$ is homotopic to a wedge of $n$ circles when $n\geq 1$.  Then you only need to show $W_1$ and $W_0$ are not homeomorphic.  This follows because $W_1$ can be disconnected by removing a point while $W_0$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$, cannot.